# How do you calculate DPDK mempool requirements?

Tags: dpdk

How do you figure out what settings need to be used to correctly configure a DPDK mempool for your application?

Specifically using rte_pktmbuf_pool_create():

- n, the number of elements in the mbuf pool
- cache_size
- priv_size
- data_room_size

EAL arguments:

- n number of memory channels
- r number of memory ranks
- m amount of memory to preallocate at startup
- in-memory no shared data structures
- IOVA mode
- huge-worker-stack

My setup:

- 2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6348 CPU @ 2.6 Ghz

  - 28 cores per socket
  - Max 3.5 Ghz
  - Hyperthreading disabled
  - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
  - Kernel 5.15.0-53-generic
  - Cores set to performance governor
  - 4 x Sabrent 2TB Rocket 4 Plus in RAID0 Config
  - 128 GB DDR4 Memory
  - 10 1GB HugePages (Can change to what is required)
- 1 x Mellanox ConnectX-5 100gbe NIC

  - `31:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]`
  - Firmware-version: 16.35.1012
- UDP Source:

  - 100 gbe NIC
  - 9000 MTU Packets
  - ipv4-udp packets

Will be receiving 10GB/s UDP packets over a 100gbe link. Plan is to strip the headers and write the payload to a file. Right now trying to get it working for 2GB/s to a single queue.

Reviewed the DPDK Programmers guide: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/mempool_lib.html
Also searched online but the resources seem limited. Would appreciate any help or a push in the right direction.

Comment: Please update max queues configured for solution to suggest ? Is the payload size always 9000B?

Comment: @VipinVarghese payload will always be 9000B. Right now I am working with one queue but eventually I will want 4 queues per card, two per port.

Comment: answer to your query is been shared, pleas go through the same and accpet|upvote to help others to find the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the updates from comments the question can be summarized as

> what are the correct settings to be used for DPDK mbuf|mempool which needs to handle 9000B UDP payload for processing 10Gbps packets on 100Gbps MLX CX-5 NIC with single or multiple queues

Let me summarize my suggestions below for this unique case

[for 100Gbps]

1. as per [MLX DPDK performance report](http://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_22_07_NVIDIA_Mellanox_NIC_performance_report.pdf) for test case 4, for packet size `1518` we get theoretical and practical Million Packets per sec as `8.13`
2. Hence for 9000B payload this will be, `9000B/1518B=6` is around `8.13/6 = 1.355 MPps`
3. With MLX CX-5 1 queue achieve a mx of 36Mpps - so with 1 queue and JUMBo enabled, you should get the 9000B into a single queue

***note: 10Gbps it will be 0.1355Mpps***

Settings for MBUF or mempool:

1. if your application logic requires 0.1 seconds to process the payload, I recommend you to use `3 * max expected packets`. So roughly 10000 packets
2. Each payload has total size of 10000B (data_room_size) as single contiguous buffer.
3. priv_size is wholly dependant upon your logic to store metadata

Note: in case multiple queue, I always configure for worst case scenario, that is `I assume there will be elephant flow which can fall onto specific queue. So if with 1 queue you have created 10000 elements, for multiple queues I use 2.5 * 10000`

Comment: Correction: 10 Gigabytes per second on a 100gigabit link. Does that change your answer?

Comment: for actual 10Gbps on 100Gbps link for 9000B you can safely use 5000 mbuf in mempool with size 10K data_len. again it varies on your processing logic, if you keep it longer, then assign more mbuf